# FastAPI StreamingResponse with picamera2 - browser refresh problem

Tags: raspberry-pi, fastapi, picamera

I'm trying to make FastAPI server which streams MJPEG from Raspberry Pi via picamera2 library. It works, but when I reload browser on /mjpeg multiple times, it will stuck. But with [this example](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/blob/main/examples/mjpeg_server.py) it works perfectly - you can reload browsers as many times as you want. Can you spot the problem?

For server I'm using uvicorn with default settings.

Thanks!

```
import io
import os
from threading import Condition
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import JpegEncoder
from picamera2.outputs import FileOutput
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, StreamingResponse


app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins="http://localhost:8000",
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


class StreamingOutput(io.BufferedIOBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        with self.condition:
            self.frame = buf
            self.condition.notify_all()


picam2 = Picamera2()
picam2.configure(picam2.create_video_configuration(main={"size": (640, 480)}))
output = StreamingOutput()
picam2.start_recording(JpegEncoder(), FileOutput(output))


def get_frame():
    try:
        while True:
            with output.condition:
                output.condition.wait()
                frame = output.frame
                yield (
                    b"--frame\r\n" b"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + frame + b"\r\n"
                )
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error! Frames")


@app.get("/mjpeg", response_class=StreamingResponse)
def mjpeg(request: Request):
    try:
        frames = get_frame()
        response = StreamingResponse(
            frames,
            headers={
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache, private",
                "Pragma": "no-cache",
            },
            media_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame",
        )
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error! Route")
```

Comment: Sorry, it can be /mjpeg aswell.

Comment: What do you mean with “gets stuck”? Does the feed stop? Does the server stop responding to requests? What gets stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try the following:

```
def get_frame():
    try:
        while True:
            with output.condition:
                output.condition.wait()
                frame = output.frame

            ret = b'--FRAME\r\n'
            ret += b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n'
            ret += f'Content-Length: {len(frame)}\r\n\r\n'.encode()
            ret += frame
            ret += b'\r\n'
            yield ret
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning('Removed streaming client!')

@app.get('/mjpeg', response_class=StreamingResponse)
def stream():
    response = StreamingResponse(
        get_frame(),
        headers={
            'Age': '0',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME'
        }
    )
    return response
```

The above code runs as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).